# Random Range orders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I want to make a special random.

```
private Randomizer getNumberRnd;
getNumberRnd = new Randomizer(1, 10, true);
    firstNumber = getNumberRnd.getRandom();
```

I want to get 6 random numbers to be close.

For example: 7,6,5,8,9,5

As I see from 1 to 10, so how do I get these numbers random and close?

Comment: You want the numbers to be close, but from a "large" interval. I don't get your question, exactly.

Comment: Yes, I think it's quite clearly explained. I want 6 numbers from this interval but close

Comment: No, it wasn't clear. If the goal is that, pick a single number from this interval, let this be "a"; then, pick 5 other numbers from a-2 to a+2, or whatever will be the offset, using a new rand.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you want your number to not diverge from more than +- 2 and be close to 12. You could simply do

```
int randomOffset = Random.Range(-2, 3); // For ints, the upper value is exclusive
int value = 12 + randomOffset;
```

This will give you a value in the range

> 10, 11, 12, 13, 14

Now if you don't want it to be around twelve, but around a random value and keep them between 1 and 10

```
int randomPivot = Random.Range(3, 9);
int randomOffset = Random.Range(-2, 3); // For ints, the upper value is exclusive
int value = randomPivot + randomOffset;
```

And now, you want 6 values around the pivot, so we do

```
int[] randomValues = new int[6];
int randomPivot = Random.Range(3, 9);
for(int i = 0; i<6; ++i)
{
    int randomOffset = Random.Range(-2, 3);
    randomValues[i] = randomPivot + randomOffset;
}
```

Now `random values` contains 6 values that are random, but close to each other and are all between 1 and 10

Comment: randomValues[i] = randomPivot + randomOffset;
here's a mistake

Comment: Woops, I edited the answer. it was a type in the for loop.